# Sidekiq Web UI not loading or mounting or something with no errors in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, sidekiq

Im using sidekiq with Rails 4.2.8 and its working fine, the only issue is the Web UI on production servers. I can load the UI fine locally but if I deploy it to a production server than the UI will not load and there are no errors. Im mounting in my routes like so..

```
OptimoUi::Application.routes.draw do
  require 'sidekiq/web'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  authenticate :admin_user do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
```

And when I got to the /sidekiq route after authenticating with active admin I have just a blank screen. No errors in the console, nothing in the rails log, not even a 404 or anything just nothing. The only time there is a something is in the nginx access log where If I refresh that page I get a 304

```
157.130.220.250 - ross [10/Oct/2017:15:23:20 +0000] "GET /sidekiq HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Maybe I am missing something in Nginx configuration? Here is a some of the conf with allowed headers

```
  location @application {
    add_header X-yKind rails-api-1;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Client-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;

    proxy_hide_header Clear-Site-Data;

    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(static|tou|csv_export|accounts|api) {
    root  /opt/optimo/current/public;
    try_files $uri @application;
  }

  location ~ ^/(admin|manage) {
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    try_files $uri @application;
  }

  ## default location ##
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
  }
```

And I have also uncommented this line in the rails configuration.

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

But nothing seems to work and I am stumped by lack of errors anywhere.

Comment: Can you also check Rails, Sidekiq production logs?
And try to use curl or web inspector to check what exactly do you have in response.

Comment: The production logs are empty and if I run a curl request to that route using localhost I get `<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/admin/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>`

Comment: And if I make a curl request to the domain name instead of localhost it looks like im getting back a totally unrelated html file that is loading assets from the apps assets directory...

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up a proxy_pass for the /sidekiq location in the Nginx configuration.

```
location ~^/sidekiq {
    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
  }
```

It was rendering the html of one of our Ember pages for some reason.